# Firefox Add-on Delete event listener

Tags: events, firefox, listener, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

i have some problem in firefox add-on/jetpack.

There its the event listener:

```
tab.on('deactivate', cleardata);
```

I need delete the deactivate event listener.

I guess i need something like that

```
tab.removeListener('deactivate', cleardata);
```

But something was worng in the code, dont stop the listener.

Grettings, Marcos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet works as expected for me:

```
var count = 0;

function myListener(tab) {
    count++;
    console.log("Event number " + count);
    if (count == 3)
    {
        console.log("Removing listener after third event");
        tab.removeListener('deactivate', myListener);
    }
}

function setupTabTest(tab) {
    tab.on('deactivate', myListener);
}
```

(You need to call `setupTabTest` with some existing Tab object.)

Does this code work for you? If so, please give more information about the part of your code which is not working. Try to reduce it to the simplest example which illustrates the error.

Comment: Yeah, there the problem...
`votetab.on('deactivate', end);
votetab.removeListener('deactivate', end);`

It isn't work, maybe im misinterpreting the deactivate event.

Exacly what does the Deactivate Event?

Comment: @Marcos The [Deactivate Event](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html#deactivate) is fired when a tab stops being the active tab (e.g. you switch to another tab). You'll have to give more information because I can't reproduce your problem. Try running and understanding the code I wrote, and see if there is something that you're doing differently.